# How to include logging scope into the log file using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog, microsoft-extensions-logging

I'm using `NLog.Extensions.Logging`.

When registering a logger factory using the method `AddNLog()`, it is possible to enable logging scope using `NLogProviderOptions.IncludeScopes`.

But how to make NLog write logging scope to a file?

I haven't found anything similar in the list of [available layouts](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layouts)

Comment: Does this post help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-scopes?

Comment: @MikeParkhill unlikely, he asking how to write which scope is being used in the log, not how to use scoped logging

Comment: yeah, that post calls out that it will be included in the log if configured properly - thought it might help them see what they're missing

Comment: If you just want to add an additional logevent property, then this might be of interest: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An example:

Log like this:

```cs
// logger is here of type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
using (logger.BeginScope(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("userid", request.UserId) }))
{
   logger.LogDebug("My log message");
}
```

Render like this: `${mdlc:userid}`.

For example in the file target:

```xml
 <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
     layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message}${exception:format=ToString}, user: ${mdlc:userid}" 
     fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}.log" />
```

Note: `NLogProviderOptions.IncludeScopes` is enabled by default.

#### NLog directly

The syntax is a bit clumsy, but that is because Microsoft's abstraction is a bit limited. See also this issue: [.NET - Logging structured data without it appearing in the text message](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/668)

If you refer NLog directly, you could also do:

```cs
using (NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.SetScoped("userid", request.UserId))
{
   // logger here of type NLog.Logger
   logger.Info("My log message");
}
```

Also this is rendered with `${mdlc:userid}`

More examples and different scopes for NLog explained [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context)

#### Docs

PS: I have updated [available layouts](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=scope), so you could find it easier :)

[image]

Comment: It isn't necessary to pass the KeyValuePair array when creating a scope. I'm using template string with params, and it works well. Like this: `logger.BeginScope("{userid}", request.UserId)`

Comment: Answer and docs uses different syntax. So its ${mdlc:userid} or ${mdlc:item=userid}?

Comment: Both are fine. `item` is the default for this renderer, so you could skip it

Comment: With NLog 5, MDLC has been replaced by ScopeProperty https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeProperty-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 1):

New (in V5) is to use `${scopenested}`.

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeNested-Layout-Renderer.